# Compass animation without ease things

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I'm trying to get an compass sass animation running with endless rotation. Thats working but at the end of each rotation the item seems to slow down a little bit (like easing) but there's no easing set by myself and in documentation any value is set to `false`. What could be the reason for tht problem?

This is my animation made with [compass animate](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation):

```
@include keyframes(rotation) {
    0% {
        @include transform(rotate(0deg));
    }

    100% {
        @include transform(rotate(359deg));
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `animation-timing-function` CSS property is set to `ease` [by default](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-animations/#animation-timing-function). To override this and make your animation smooth you'll need to set this property to `linear` where you're calling the animation:

```css
animation-timing-function: linear;
```

Comment: Minor typo: `animation-timing-function: linear;`